# Getting null value while calling a static threadlocal getter method from a static method

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, thread-local

In my code, Class A has static ThreadLocal variable user id.

```
    class A {
       private static ThreadLocal<Integer>                            
             userId = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

       public static int getUserId() {
           ....
       }

       public static int setUserId() {
          ....
       }
    }
```

I set the userId value in class B. My code, after setting the value in class B, is calling a static method of class C.

```
 class C {
     public static someMethod() {
         int userId = A.getUserId();
         ....
         ....
     }
 }
```

In my local server, I am getting the expected userId in someMethod. But On a production server, I am getting a default value from userId.

Is there anything wrong in my code. Do I not supposed to call a ThreadLocal getter method from a static method.

Please Help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing, but it sounds like the call to A and C might occur from different threads. What is the full flow? Can you post the code which calls to A and C in relation to each other.

Comment: Please show the class hierarchy, including the definition of class `B`